# Page templates in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can templates of web part pages be made? I have a web part page that contains several web parts all with different views of 2 different lists. I want to be able to template this page and allow users to re-create it at will.
The list also contains a workflow. Would this workflow and list(s) be included in the page or would I just be best to template the whole site with the page, lists and workflows included?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your requirement correctly, you need to create a page layout with all the web parts that you want to have with the design or structure. you can either create it from SharePoint designer or deploy it from Visual Studio.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes but I want a couple of lists to be included not just the layout - if that makes sense!

Comment: Lists are part of site structures, so you have to create your structures behind, independently from if/how you're going to present their data in your pages. You can include some web parts (such as ListViewWebPart in your case) static in the web part zone in a page layout.

Comment: JazzyN,

  Yes you can even do that in the methods i mentioned above. follow http://www.jamestsai.net/Blog/post/How-to-use-event-handler-to-add-web-part-to-web-part-page.aspx for more detailed information. 

   As you are planning to allow the user to create the page with all the pre defined structure of web parts loaded into the page, I'm suggesting it.

let me know if you have any questions.